# Get the value of an input field in IE using AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get the value on an input field in IE using auto hot key.

I'm using AHK version 1.1.19.01 on windows 8.1 using IE 11.0.9600.17498

I have a simple (local) html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="area2" id="area2" />
</body>
</html>
```

I type something in the text box and then run the ahk script (which should just tell me the value I typed in).

This is my ahk script:

```
wb := IEGet("Page1")
WinActivate Page1
txt := wb.Document.All.area2.Value
MsgBox % txt

IEGet(Name="")        ;Retrieve pointer to existing IE window/tab
{
    IfEqual, Name,, WinGetTitle, Name, ahk_class IEFrame
    {
        Name := ( Name="New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer" ) ? "about:Tabs" : RegExReplace( Name, " - (Windows|Microsoft) Internet Explorer" )
    }

    For wb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
    {
        If ( wb.LocationName = Name ) && InStr( wb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
        {
            Return wb
        }
    }
}
```

The message box is blank.

I have tried various syntax to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

The IEGet function was copied from some web page - its not mine, but it works.

NOTES:
To find the ahk version:

```
msgbox % "my ahk version: " A_AhkVersion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example ( win7 v1.1.19.01 IE11 )

```
FileSelectFile, path

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.visible := true
wb.navigate(path)

while wb.readyState!=4 || wb.document.readyState != "complete" || wb.busy
    continue
return

f6::
msgbox % wb.document.all["area2"].value
return
```

I have sometimes also had problems with IEGet() and IE9+

but here is the function I use to get an active IE Object

```
WBGet(WinTitle="ahk_class IEFrame", Svr#=1) {               ;// based on ComObjQuery docs
   static msg := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "str", "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")
        , IID := "{0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"   ;// IID_IWebBrowserApp
;//     , IID := "{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"   ;// IID_IHTMLWindow2
   SendMessage msg, 0, 0, Internet Explorer_Server%Svr#%, %WinTitle%
   if (ErrorLevel != "FAIL") {
      lResult:=ErrorLevel, VarSetCapacity(GUID,16,0)
      if DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr","{332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}", "ptr",&GUID) >= 0 {
         DllCall("oleacc\ObjectFromLresult", "ptr",lResult, "ptr",&GUID, "ptr",0, "ptr*",pdoc)
         return ComObj(9,ComObjQuery(pdoc,IID,IID),1), ObjRelease(pdoc)
      }
   }
}
```

It Query's the IWebBrowserApp interface and returns a usable IE Comobject

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

wb := WBGet("Page1")
txt := wb.Document.All["area2"].value
MsgBox % txt
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Message box showing a blank with this one as well.  I tried using the other IID line and got the same result.  I wonder if the class ID is different in windows 8.1.  I also tried adding the value in the html to see if it was that that was trying to be read, but again, the same blank.

Comment: Checked registry and it is the same class id.

Comment: Both work great here, so I don't know what else to say, this has worked for others with win 8.1 and IE 11 before so i'm not sure whats happening on your end sorry... maybe try and post the code you tested with and also try running as admin

Comment: Tried run as admin - same result.  Before, I just used the WBGet function.  Today, I thought I'd try your script in its entirety, which navigates to the page for you, which is not what I want and I have noticed that things do work better when ahk has created the ie object as opposed to using an already open page.  I get the following error:  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.  Specifically: readyState. Line #016. msg := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "str"....

Comment: Just thought of something else.  I am running the html page locally (ie. c:\ahk\page1.html).  I wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: That's what it was - I guess it doesn't work with the file protocol, just the http protocol

Comment: Also noticed, that WBGet doesn't work when multiple tabs are open. IEGet does.

Comment: great you got it working and it also works with multiple tabs WbGet just has more then one parameter one for the title and one for the server number.